# Display image from http response with image content type

Tags: javascript, html, image, httpresponse, content-type

Let's say I have url and don't know what it will return. I perform ajax call to that url with `javascript` and get the content. So I test it's content-type and decide how to show response in my webpage.
In case it is json or html or any other text, I append the formatted content as I need.

Now when the content type is image, I get the image's data in response, which is not base64 encoded. I need to show the image in a regular `<img>` tag of course. And here is where I get stuck.

Is there a way to show image from it's content data?

**EDIT**

Just to make it clear, hear is what I get in response:

```
"�PNG


IHDR��Nn�tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<fiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0-c060 61.134777, 2010/02/12-17:32:00        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="xmp.did:8E935AD20E206811822AA1DC23D37A5E" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:606C15E3DC2311E2A81EB553B5E13CE0" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:606C15E2DC2311E2A81EB553B5E13CE0" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CS5 Macintosh"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:0E49679B0D20681192B0DE3AF6794EF0" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:8E935AD20E206811822AA1DC23D37A5E"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>�,��
3IDATx�읿R�JGI&m�����I����؅K((MC7�nH����%���ef����0���u�� i%����:�`K�{�ӷ������u�>���(����(����(����(����(����(����(����(����(����(��((��((��((��((��(���&؅�b1�ϟ׬V��t���j�T*��e��R��t�����c0�&��|}yy����ns�|Cc�l���7k�����ju:�Eٴ����")Ye�
W�U�Mu+"n�����3
����zzz*c��%����K�g4�&�T���z=_����G���@ū�(�Rġ�ng��^������@�F���2G_��],t�Fb:�����^������@٨  ��n�F#�`����|���<��_!��z���,��?�p}��U�����I}���
��h�6N��}||$hIY���p^IR?��
(k*��D�c���)�����s�*l�e�n-}��o��f:��Pְ[.��ʚKdP�be
�!9��,ʺh��!�r����|����>}��o����λW.��#�5�    
�5IY)Zx�'ʚ4�:88��P��̫����P֟Z��玍�czeM�51(()��4����0f�P�03���A�'���Y�5)he�xTʚ�����|��eQ�$�j�jF���~AY�~_������A��`����dOZ�=��f��%�{�}��Qi6�����+U,ʚ4N��E��(�J9^s�m�e� ǜ#bQ6�5�D,��G٘���e��?~��(?h3����*V
��
!��-V*���[ڜ�݉,���v�����2����    �Pְ8�PeQ��d0�g.eM�I�'�����}�
wˠlb�F��|������GٝY/..^^^dl���nU0����hv������������)m�������ec��z�yK�����ְn淳9������=�lT����4�q�'''�E)j��6q��b��:��T�U���F����%�܈M�� � �ْ���,��7�6�6�Ŭ���[ ��!;���7)x�9)�/�����S�*��������i��GAJ�~����jMh*�j�f�Y��UV�k8��G9r�v�^����O����\W 9}^V�q�`(�ʄb)+�9���IVj��k���������K�x�-֊��Z�Pe���h4�L�k�O8[*3ާ�;�`���b���qAFi�(U��\.�C�6_�ݮo(�Ri8���`P��k���P�դ&�|?Ǒ#���o=�V��dĵp�K���h�I  N�)%fY�I���Ǡ�LpWq��v"�ʦ��*��4^G4bsn��J7h�^*�z�����{���V�����(+}#����=�$�(+�z!H�><<���SJD�¯e� �Q6��xAxuu%rx�]v)�4�Y%�d�rK���z��x��Q�
:;�h�Iu�mZ�h��bC�������� F���g�וּ�B�AY��lje�Q]Ā\�V�y5ʆ��3�rߔ�x�_qN����� h�W6t�S�<??{{t��h8�l�ș:�  ��mE��Q�;Y*{��&�`0�x�������(V   f|��Yˆ���qfH�Z��z��i\�S3�LP6�/�� h��nП������>γ?NP6��2LaA/VP؜q!�2�Q6k�U��oWa�(��PK��+��V���(ky�0_�g��fIe����*;����t��A?W\)�qb��մ�lb���*�ex�˦y#�ir\�4��bWs�:9�
]�m�����K��=�瘲�����_�)��K���O�Ќ�R6�x�Ƽ"J���}Q�����)+�^�ymS�������kP��B6蔪�J}���/��٘�+�COo���f�0�1��5OY��{O�ێ����Ӫ1Q6��P�ޔ�䌬ɑc��:�����G�>gd���0e��{��Уț��L�73LY}�wsO��*��t��p�fe�*�\k�d�f*k5�o�Ԭa�jUx��F9�6G+e�e�R�n*���0��k��10��v6
�$`Vm�_w�v���pm�Y#0��ժ*�T6J-�j��*U��&���Γ���Z�X)kzU`�vyW">�9��|�)��]����F�;�e�E���*(�����ʂg����%�}���,�,��,�,�&���/���Q���0��0e#�0��T*�lZ-�~!�@R��V5l��j���>Em�)p}}mֹ���뫉m=�χá��ׁ���^�g\�e��.b��߿Y$�U% �v:�JX{�up^�8���]��@��_��Z��&��t<o{W��T*1�V���+��OOO��Wr��������L-��������~�kh�J�V��ڏR�]��b�r���1�Bu_�p����zq�W2X$�o�}"�HYYS.��o��S(RK�V+��}\a�7�;�)_���A�d��1#Y$vl�{��ͭ��!���i����T�e�X�
(��((��((��((��((��((��((��((��((��((��(����(����(����(����(��`/�0a�����IEND�B`�"
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035615/using-raw-image-data-from-ajax-request-for-data-uri/20048852#20048852

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var rawResponse = "�PNG...."; // truncated for example

// convert to Base64
var b64Response = btoa(rawResponse);

// create an image
var outputImg = document.createElement('img');
outputImg.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+b64Response;

// append it to your page
document.body.appendChild(outputImg);
```

Comment: This should definitely be the canonical answer. Also, I think it'd be worth mentioning that `btoa` will work in this case, but needs help from `unescape` and `encodeURIComponent` for UTF-8.

Comment: Liked this approach. But in my case `btoa` throws this error: `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: 'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.` Even when I do `unescape(encodeURIComponent(rawResponse))`.
By the way, `unescape` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: i am using filepath to upload an image while reciving i am getting similar to the above raw data but iam not able to convert to base64 btoa is giving some other result any idea why btoa is not providing base64

Comment: Is this something different for jpegs? i have the same thing with a jpeg however this method doesn't seem to work.

After converting it all i am left with that funny icon on the frontend that displays when no image is there;

<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAQBIAEgAAO+/ve+/vRDvv71FeGlmAABNTQAqAAAACAAFARIAAwAAAAEAAQAAATEAAgAAAC4AAAhWATIAAgAAABQAAAjvv73vv71pAAQAAAABAAAI77+977+9HAAHAA....................vv73vv71uM++/vWnvv70R77+9dU/vv71c77+9BADvv70Zbe+/vQTvv71UdO+/ve+/vUXvv73vv71577+9B2t+HWjvv73vv73vv73vv73vv73vv70=">

Comment: @waqask87 did you find a solution for content-type jpeg ??

Comment: Getting error - 
DOMException [InvalidCharacterError]: Invalid character
    at new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:53:5)
    at __node_internal_ (node:internal/util:695:10)
    at btoa (node:buffer:1268:13)
    at D:\empmgt\routes\generate-id-route.js:201:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer didn't worked for me. So here's my solution:

1. I'm using `fetch` to download image, so I need to read response as `blob`:

> ```
> let data;
> fetch(url).then(response => {
>   response.blob().then(blobResponse => {
>     data = blobResponse;
>   })
> });
> ```

2. Displaying [blob as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650587/using-javascript-to-display-blob):

> ```
> const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
> document.getElementById('myImage').src = urlCreator.createObjectURL(data);
> ```

Comment: actually this is the answer that works and tutored by mozilla in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)

Comment: This's the best answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

use the [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob)

- [solution 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob#example)

  ```js
  const response = await fetch(`...`)
  const responseBlob = await response.blob()
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(responseBlob)
  document.querySelector(`body`).append(img)
  ```
- solution 2

  get the [URI.scheme.data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) from blob.  <sup>you can reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463054/9935654</sup>

  The below example (case 2) will show you the details.

### Example

This example is to get the image from some repository of GitHub.

```js
/**
 * @param {int} solutionNumber: I provide two solutions both can achieve.
 * @param {string} owner
 * @param {string} repo
 * @param {string} path
 * @param {string} branch: branch name or you can use SHA1
 * @param {string} token: Used while your repository is private. https://github.com/settings/tokens
 */
async function ShowGithubImg(solutionNumber, owner, repo, path, branch = "master", token = "") {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/contents/${path}?ref=${branch}`, {
    // method: "GET",
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
      // authorization: `token ${token}`
    }
  })
  if (!response.ok) {
    const errMsg = await response.text()
    throw Error(`${response.statusText} (${response.status}) | ${errMsg} `)
  }

  const responseBlob = await response.blob()

  const img = document.createElement('img')

  switch (solutionNumber) {
    case 1:
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(responseBlob)
      break
    case 2:
      let uriData = ""
      blob2bas64 = async (blob) => {
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader()
          reader.onload = function () { // use promise to wait until onload finished
            console.log(this.result) // you can see its media type is: application/vnd.github.v3.raw // https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/media-types
            uriData = this.result // <--- `this.result` contains a base64 data URI
            resolve()
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
        })
        await promise
      }

      await blob2bas64(responseBlob)
      img.src = `${uriData}`
      break

  }
  document.querySelector(`body`).append(img)
}

for (const solutionNumber of [1, 2]) {
  ShowGithubImg(solutionNumber, "CarsonSlovoka", "excel", "app/urls/static/app.ico", "807dd79")
}
```

### URI

@Lostsource's answer mentions [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes)
Since this question only asks about images, but some people have other formats (image/jpeg)
In fact, the format of URI.scheme.data is

> `data:<mediatype>[;base64],<data>`

you can see it on [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes)

You just need to know the `mediatype` ([common mediatype list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Common_examples_%5B10%5D)).

For example `image/jpeg`

> `data:image/jpeg;base64,<data>`

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the image to base64 using canvas [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) and then append it to the DOM like so:

```
var rawResponse = 'PNG'; // This is your response object
var encodedResponse = btoa(rawResponse);

var img = new Image();
var container = document.getElementById('newImg');

img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + encodedResponse;

img.onload = function() {
container.appendChild( img );
};
```

More information on [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: I do not have the image url in frontend, just content. I am not sure how to create a canvas with that data.

Answer (score 0):

we can get response and bind it form my HTML.

1) .ts file page : -

```
imageData : any ;

response => {
    var b64Response = btoa(response);
    this.imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + b64Response;
  }
```

2) .html file page:

```
      <img [src]="imageData" class="img-thumbnail">
```