# Error when sending params on a GET method using the fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am getting an error:

```js
[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"]
```

I am trying to do 2 API calls because one depends on the other.

Code:

```js
      const bearer = "Bearer " + user?.token;

      fetch(`${API}/getDocumentById`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: bearer,
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ document_id: doc.id }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log(`${API}/viewFile?file=${json.document.file}`);
          // This console logs returns a good value:
          // http://my-api.com/api/viewFile?file=1620802187_MAPPA-definitiva.pdf
          fetch(`${API}/viewFile?file=${json.document.file}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Authorization: bearer,
              "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            },
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
              setImage(json.document);
            })
            .catch((viewFileError) => {
              // HERE IS WHERE IT THROWS THE ERROR
              console.log({ viewFileError });
            });

          setData(json.document);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log({ err });
        });
```

On Postman it works properly.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Headers:
[image]

Comment: ah ,wait the response is not format json.  Fetch api can decode the bytesteram to more than ust json. response.json() must call internally json .parse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requesting blob images and transforming to base64 with fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698967/requesting-blob-images-and-transforming-to-base64-with-fetch-api)

Comment: hm, looks like you are fetching pdf actually. Maybe this https://gist.github.com/devloco/5f779216c988438777b76e7db113d05c

Comment: @TheFool mmm how is that? Did you check the Postman screenshot? Postman returns just what I need. So I don't get how is that my code doesn't work.

Comment: Your console output is telling you. `  console.log(`${API}/viewFile?file=${json.document.file}`);
          // This console logs returns a good value:
          // http://my-api.com/api/viewFile?file=1620802187_MAPPA-definitiva.pdf`

Comment: you can also use postman to help you to generate the code btw. It will at least show you how its decoding the pdf.

Comment: @Reacting The postman screenshots shows us that the response to the second request is  certainly not JSON. You can check the response headers to confirm.