# Get the img src from image received from API with content-type as image/jpeg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

The API is sending data in the below format. The response headers set

```
content-type: image/jpeg
```

Tried the answers provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784145/display-image-from-http-response-with-image-content-type), but no luck as of now. Can someone suggest me a good approach. Also, I am using React in my development which shouldn't matter (just quoting).

```
"�PNG


IHDR
 4F9jiCCPICC ProfileH��WXS��[�����z�W)!�R!  $���\��bEWE] ���ˢ��bAAYuQ�7!]����;�=s�?%3�3h�r%�T�\q�4.<�9.%�Ijd0P�9���dVll�2��]�����������@��q:_�˅�    |#O"����[L˓(�<�u�0@��(p��V�t%n�I�cC|5*�+�@��3�y��G�3��b�H���xB.bE�#rs�(p9Ķ�^1�x�Ǚ�7��!~.7s+���L�Ý���Kn�|Ї5lT�4"N�?���)�
L��K���5Ľ"�����<"Qi��dlX?��ؙ�
����0qNt�J��!
�@W:]��I�X��Yh��f�tJ��Z�!e�T��\�_��G��D����P�Q�c„d�)[拒�!ր�I���U dG�H�q��-!��Ã��X~�4,Ne_�+��*q�U�`�0!BY�4�;?��*�y�qQ���!��ܱ�81^��+��S��)��X�=n.� W��!v��ǫ��Iypq*��I^l�2N� �;:V�D6L �-LY@��U�ߔ#a�� ��J38#y`D����Ȇ��
@>��*�� c`4`F6xq.�9�]>0K<�- <��?�sa��xs`S��{�����5Q*�|�#SsВJ!FÈv�!���Q��+����͞��JxB�Ih#ܝ,*������T�H���5����q��qnqw臅B�P�Vŭ�
��e�ݯ��#;�Q�0r��Ǚ�C,�Z_e��C�f����]������[���a'�X#V��    ���S���l`u
z��'��Ꮻ̹ڹ���r,O0=O���S$3��La��&G�s�tuvu@�Q�}�c|C��o�‡�����7~�E��{�n��o:�jh�8��'��+u��A���p�`la>���� 
F��R�$Xe!\�R0
��A1(+�Z�l��n�u��g�%p����i�@7x�!!4�� ��‸"�H�D!qH
��d"bD��B ��*d�
�B~A�"'�H+ry�t"o�O(�RQ]��FG��(�DЉh&:-@��eh9Z��Ekѓ�%�&چ�B{0��c�sļ16��b����`eX%V�5���:ֆuaq"NǙ�#\�x"�ç�s��|7^��Ư��n�+�F0"8|    �8B&a��PF�I8B8�R;�=�Hdm�^p/���3�K�����M�V�Sb�D2 9��I1$.)�TLZO�K:A�Fj'��������������
�����W���B���E�"��c�|��r�r�
���GѦ�P�)   �,�|J9��r���N]]�\�G}��H}�z������?Ru��T6uUN]F�Em�ޥ���hִ Z*-���VE;E{D�ՠk8ip4�s5*4j5�i��$kZi�4'ih�iҼ�٥Eֲ�bkq��hUhպ�գM�vю���^��G��v�I�Z'T��S��]��S:F����<���z�.Q�F����[��O�E�[OG�]/Io�^��1�6ưfp9�匃�[�OÌ���  �-V3�ڰ������%���o�2`�d�4�3xh���5�f����a�p��~�y�K�~�5�7�3�i���Q���q���x��)�.�I�I����&��t�S����/�zL3�Y�<��632�0��m3k1�3�1O4/4�o�Ђb�m�a�Ƣ٢���r��,�j�{Vd+o+��:�sV�m���Y�Yw���pl
l�m��lm��V�ް#�y�e�m��j��{��+�8��"�M�##|F�GT���Hud9�;V;>vb8E9:�9�i92u�ʑ�F~u�p�q��|�E�e�K�K��[W{W�k��
7�[��\�z�7�����w<�c<y4{|���z�xvzYz�ym����������'�g�O��G_O�<߃��9�e����e3J0jǨ����\�m�m̀���m�f�����'AA���A/Xv�,�^��`�`i��l_�lvSR����!�Q�yXfXuXw�G���BDd�ʈ�c�S���5z��ӑ����
�O�죤Q
c�1�Ǭ� �*Z]b81�c���N��u,ql�؊���\�fŝ���O���>!8ay��D�Dybs�f҄����!ɫ��ƍ7{ܥ�QJ}*)5)ugj����kǷO�P<��D���'^�d8)gұɚ����Ғ���}��p+�=����<6o�?����)������X�ё韹:�S(,v�آ
�7YY[�>d�d����I�ٟ����{T�#���b2e��V���X�6�w�ک��H�N"�(��Ӆ���r[�B��������iI�Mמ.�~y���%3^��<�ɛ�<�l��Y�g�fo���I��<�bn���y��vϧ�Ϟ�[�s�¿$/h(2.�W�ta���b�bi��E~��,���,q[�~��~��R�Ҳ��KyK/���S�O��2��,�\�yq�xŭ��+w��^U����1�k�0ה��k����˶�����k+�*�_o�~����nVW��h�q������m�\��xK�O[E[�l�V[i]Y���=��I;����s�NÝ�;���j���t�WU��=˫�jyu��    {���W_�X�m?c�p@~��/i��:y�������V�7�)�Ejg�v� ���S�[��>����p�W�_w5�5V�;��8�x���'z�$M]'3O>m��|�ԸS7N�=�r&����agO�c�;q��|��G/z_���y�����#�y�v�ų���ו��>WZG��x�����gopn\�}��V�;�'�n�ÿ�q7��{�����{@xP�P�a�#�G������ͳ���Ǘ��?������3ٳ��E�i��^����p�h���r���W�W}]�h�������y�{\w����K������_�=�=�����P�kл����s��?��������ݗ���_����K�R��Q�
����.xNH��m��ʻ�� ����   +�� @
��xv`������P7���Y�����
oB����w���"�������e�.MS�wP��ak���O�?$���w9��E����_z��̑c�eXIfMM*>F(�iN����x�
 �4ASCIIScreenshotN�z�  pHYs%%IR$��iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 6.0.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
         <exif:PixelYDimension>2100</exif:PixelYDimension>
         <exif:PixelXDimension>3360</exif:PixelXDimension>
         <exif:UserComment>Screenshot</exif:UserComment>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
L���iDOT(=Vy�)m@IDATx콿�m˗�u�C
```

Comment: please show code that related to this data, which api you used to get this data?

Comment: What you are sending from react is a buffer. You should use `Formidable` or `Multer` in the backend to handle it properly(parse)