# Base64 image is not displayed in the correct form

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I'm trying to display an base64 image. It has to work in two different scenarios, but the image is just shown once.

Ejs is working fine:

```
<img id="host-img" src="data:image/<%=justtalk.image.contentType%>;base64,<%=justtalk.image.data.toString('base64')%>">
```

Iterating through a loop doesn't work:

```
<script>
    const socket = io('/start');

    socket.on("receiveRooms", (room, callback) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
            setTimeout("", 3000);
            var data2 = '<img id="host-img" src="data:image/'+room[i].image.contentType+';base64,'+room[i].image.data.toString('base64')+'"> '

                $(data2).prependTo('#');
                
        }    
    })
</script>
```

I can't see the difference

Comment: Shouldn't the second code line also use the `<%= %>` notation? It's EJS as well, I assume.

Comment: No, it's in a script tag and it's getting its data from socket.io.

Comment: You cannot have HTML markup like `<img ...>` inside a `<script>` tag. Can you post more context of that code?

Comment: it's not a buffer, like on the server. try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784145/display-image-from-http-response-with-image-content-type