# Loading Image in JavaScript with Bearer token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I am loading an image in JS like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
..
};
img.src = src;
```

This will work, but I have realized that I must secure my images on the server side with OAuth 2 (as with the rest of the application) and this will effect in me simply receiving a 401 Unauthorized.

This is an *angular* app and I do have an interceptor adding the Authorization header consequently for all the angular service requests to the server, but in this case of course - the interceptor is not used because the call is not made in an angular context.

**Any ideas to how I can add the Authorization header to the get request?**

Comment: How is the application being served? node.js? IIS?

Comment: By .NET WebApi 2. The image is returned by a method implemented as a REST GET controller method and this will be deployed in Azure, so yeah.. IIS.

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997406/force-http-interceptor-in-dynamic-ngsrc-request will get you on right path.

Comment: Thank you @PrashantPalikhe but unfortunately in this situation it will not help me. I am trying to *programmatically* load img into variable, I do not even have an img element (I could create that to programmatically though, but I don´t think that is the way to go).

Answer (score 10):

In case you have limited possibilies at server side it is also possible to invoke a `GET` `XMLHttpRequest` request with the appropriate `access_token` and set the image `src` with a [data URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) build from the response encoded with `base64` as follow :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','https://dl.content.com/contentfile.jpg', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + oauthToken.access_token);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    var base64 = btoa(raw);
    var src = "data:image;base64," + base64;

    document.getElementById("image").src = src;
};

request.send();
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add the bearer token to the URL:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
..
};
img.src = src + '?access_token=mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM';
```

That, at least is how the OAuth 2 spec reads:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.3

And although this methodology has a number of drawbacks, the authors forsaw issues with things of this nature, which is why it is there.

Comment: Good enough solution, but requires work on the server. I have very limited privileges to change things on the server side.

Comment: won't this break any kind of caching ?

Comment: @axwell Sure... But intrinsically, the OAuth'd content shouldn't be cached anyway.