# How to override angular ngSrc directive to append request header?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, x-http-method-override

I want to append a authentication token to the angular js ngSrc url request. So how can I pass this token with `ngSrc` directive?

Comment: Use an http interceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http-src instead of ng-src and it will fetch images using the $http service - meaning Authorization headers added via interceptors will be present - then build a Blob and set the src to an objectURL.

Reference:https://github.com/dougmoscrop/angular-img-http-src

Answer (score 1):

ngSrc is not using $http internally, so the interceptor alone will not work. It just sets the src-attribute.
From my point of view you will have to write a custom directive like"ngHttpSrc", which is using the $http services.

see: [Force HTTP interceptor in dynamic ngSrc request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997406/force-http-interceptor-in-dynamic-ngsrc-request)

Answer (score 0):

Like JB mentioned in comments, use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

```js
// alternatively, register the interceptor via an anonymous factory
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      // manipulate the request here
      // You can filter specific requests if you want
      config.headers.token ="whatever";
      return config;
    }
  };
});
```