# Angular HTTP Interceptors for media type requests

Tags: angular, html5-video, media, angular-http-interceptors, angular12

I'm using HTML5 tag to play a video in my angular app. The video source is getting form REST service by express(nodejs). The API is required JWT token in AUTH header. I implemented HTTP Interceptor to add AUTH header. it works fine for other requests. But it is not working for media type http requests made by HTML5 element.

this is my Interceptor.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   constructor() { }
   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       request = request.clone({
           setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer <token>` }
       });
      return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Please help me to get this work. or suggest alternative . Thank you

Comment: I think Angular interceptors only intercept requests from HttpClient,  I could be wrong about that but I did find this solution using a pipe to make the src request with the httpclient which would get caught by the interceptor.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463201/3131085

Comment: Thanks. I got you idea. video src request directly made by browser. interceptor cannot do anything.

Comment: @MadushankaSampath Did you get solution? I've same requirement, I tried the pipe but its not working. can you share your solution here. Thanks

Comment: @Sathishkumar, i store the auth token in cookie. then media requests goes with it. i changed backend authentication also. and i know the solution is not the best one. but works