# unable to download excel file using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'service url',
   type: 'POST',
   async : true,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){

   },
   error: function(err){}
});
```

I can see the file in my `Content-disposition` in the chrome inspector and the response shows an encrypted value in the inspector.

However, no file is being downloaded. What is missing here?

Comment: It looks like you're not passing any data to that url, so why not just link to the file directly?

Comment: `false` is not a registered MIME type and, since you don't have any `data` there isn't any content to describe the contentType of.

Comment: I am getting the file as a POST . Can you provide some code for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Disposition` will influence what happens when you load a resource in a browser window.

It doesn't do anything when you are handling the response manually with JavaScript.

If you want to trigger a download from that point, you'd need to handle the response, generate a `data:` scheme URI and set `location` to it.

It would be simpler to submit a form to the destination URL in the first place (unless you don't need POST in which case you can just set `location` to it).

Comment: do u mean success: function(data){ window.location.href = data.url}?

Comment: No, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035615/using-raw-image-data-from-ajax-request-for-data-uri for example.