# How to load a image file into JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I was retrieving an image from parse using a url, like this

```
var imgPaht = user.get("ProfilePic");

    $('<img src="' + imgPaht + '">').load(function() {
        $(this).width(400).height(400).appendTo('#profile_pic');
    })
```

Now in parse, the image is not held as a string, its held as a file. How do I change the above line to work with a file and not a url.

I've tried

```
var profilePhoto = profile.get("ProfilePic");
$("profileImg")[0].src = profilePhoto.url();
```

[image: Parse backend]
Error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: This is probably answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035615/using-raw-image-data-from-ajax-request-for-data-uri  but does not use/require jQuery, just plain JS.

Comment: when you say "file" is it Base64 as in answer? or other?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've checked, it certainly is a object...

Answer (score 0):

Encoded image file data will not insert directly into an `img` tags `src` property. It must be decoded first into raw image data and then assigned to the `src` property prefixed with `data:`.

See [Using raw image data from ajax request for data URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035615/using-raw-image-data-from-ajax-request-for-data-uri) for more information on how to do this.