# AJAX returning link not image

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Im getting link instead of image.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "image.php",
    contentType: "image/png",
    success: function(result){
        $('.image').text(result);
    }
});

$image = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png";
echo '<img src="'.$image.'"></img>';

<div class="image"></div>
```

Returns text instead of image:

```
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png"></img>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jquery .ajax load image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image)

Comment: Im using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I dont think it could work, Im taking info from mysql and then refreshing image with AJAX.

Comment: I am not sure if you're using the `<img>` tag correctly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Check the resultant source after the ajax call runs ... you are putting the image as the src attribute of the element... not the path to the image as is required

Comment: It would be possible to convert the image data that you are getting from the request and converting it to a data url that can be used as the image source as is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035615/using-raw-image-data-from-ajax-request-for-data-uri)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`$('.image').text(result);`

with

`$('.image').html(result);`

It will work fine. `text()` outputs string and `html()` outputs html markup

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "image.php",
    contentType: "image/png",
    success: function(result){
        $('.image').html(result); //change text to html
    }
});
```

Text is used to inject a text node into the element, which isn't interpreted as html. The html() method writes html into the element and is interpreted as such.

Comment: I thought it was self explanatory. But, good point @JayBlanchard. I'll expand on why.