# Retrieving image blob via api, storing object url in local storage, image errors out upon refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, blob

I am trying to prevent from having to call the fetch for the profile pic upon loading the page. I get the image as a blob, and I convert it into an object url and then store it in the local storage. I noticed that upon refreshing the page the image is erroring out and I am not sure why that is the case, does the object url not save in local storage? If so how can I save the data for the image?

```
axios({
        url:   '/users/avatar',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        },
        data: {avatar: avatarUrl},
        responseType: 'blob',
      }).then((response) => {
        log(response);
        let blob = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
        localStorage.setItem('image', blob);

}
```

Comment: can you check in crome localstorage that your image is saved after fetching from api or not?

Comment: Yes so upon saving after fetching it appears like this. 
`
blob:http://localhost:3000/83bc8dcd-bb56-49cb-a9a7-81c66d872a03
`

Sometime after refreshing it turns to this 
`
/static/media/default.c7401ecc.png
`

Comment: the second one is the default image that the onerror function defaults to. I think your solution isn't working cause at thee point wheere it is turned into an object url it's already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataURL](https://base64.guru/developers/data-uri) instead of ObjectURL!
The localStorage can only manage 16 bit unicode [String object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Try replace

```
let blob = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
localStorage.setItem('image', blob);
```

... by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048852):

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(response.data);

// Convert the int array to a binary string
// We have to use apply() as we are converting an *array*
// and String.fromCharCode() takes one or more single values,
// not an array.
var raw = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);

//convert binary to ascii
var b64 = btoa(raw); 

//a DataURL is a Base64 string with a header
var dataURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64;

//do your thing
localStorage.setItem('image', dataURL);
```

For the Axios `responseType` you need to try something else than 'blob'. The options are: ['arraybuffer', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).   With 'arraybuffer' you can have:

```
var arr = response.data;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
axios({
        url:   '/users/avatar',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        },
        data: {avatar: avatarUrl},
        responseType: 'blob',
      }).then((response) => {
        log(response);
        let blob = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
        localStorage.setItem('image', JSON.stringify(blob));

}
```

get like this

```
let getImage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('image'));
```

Comment: what's the point of stringifying a string? The return value of `URL.createObjectURL` is a string, and you are further calling `JSON.stringify` on that string.